# Map Path Finding

Tags: visual, optimization, geography, mazes

I am a traveler who wants to travel from **Wellington**, NZ (orange-red circle) to **Anchorage**, USA (green-orange circle). I can only travel along the land path (black) and/or sea path (blue) as many times as I like.

Question 1: What is the shortest path? (The length of the line does not matter. The shortest distance means fewest number of stops)

Question 2: Suppose I cannot pass thru the following places:

- Bering Sea, Cape Horn, Panama, Vancouver in New World
- Bangkok, Beijing, Berlin, Dodoma in Old World

What would be the shortest path to Anchorage?

[image]

- the map is made from wikipedia under public domain

Comment: I think there should be are a route line going west from Reykjavik on the left side of the map, and one going east at the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to guess at some of the place names.

Question 1. The shortest route (fewest steps) is

> **8 steps**
>
>  Wellington
>  Easter (?) Island
>  Cape Horn
>  La Paz
>  Panama
>  Mexico City
>  Los Angeles
>  Vancouver
>  Anchorage

Question 2. The shortest route excluding various locations is

> **26 steps**
>
>  You can only get to Anchorage from Fullerton, and you can ony get there from Reykjavik, and you can only get there from Dublin, and you can only get there from New York, and so on.
>
>  There is only one route, although you could take a detour through Mumbai and Lhasa, which would add two steps:
>
>  Wellington
>  Brisbane
>  Perth
>  Île Saint-Paul (?)
>  Cape Town
>  Rio de Janiero
>  Recife (?)
>  Lagos
>  Casablanca
>  Cairo
>  Tehran
>  Astana (?)
>  Ulaanbaatar
>  Yakutsk
>  Vladivostok
>  Tokyo
>  Hong Kong
>  Guam (?)
>  Hawaii
>  Los Angeles
>  Mexico City
>  New Orleans
>  New York
>  Dublin
>  Reykjavik
>  Fullerton (?)
>  Anchorage

Having marked off the closed locations it was reasonably easy to eyeball the route.

[image]